# how can I align text/image/links within a grid <div> of the twitter bootstrap css?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I am trying to use Twitter's bootstrap CSS framework and within there so far only the grid layout.
Now I simply want to align the content of each grid cell `<div>` to the bottom.
I am obviously no CSS buff at all.

This is the html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="someprettyhighimage.gif"/></a>
        </div>
            <div class="span8">
                some text/links that need to be bottom aligned
            </div>
        </div
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot find a way to make the second column `<div>` with the text (and/or the first) be bottom aligned.

Does anybody know the css magic I would need for that?
(Or also how I would make both `<div>`s bottom-aligned?

Thanks a lot,

Sebastian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the position property of the class="row" div to relative and then set the position property of the div containing text to absolute and the bottom property to 0.

```
.row { position: relative; }
.span8 { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
```

Check it out on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/A8XE2/

Comment: Hi kdub, 
thanks for the tip!
I didn't want to overwrite the original classes (row, spanX) as they are part of the bootstrap framework and I might use them again in another context.
But I updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/A8XE2/4/ to something that seems to work.

I updated the jsfiddle

Comment: that was going to be my next suggestion...glad you got it figured out...you should mark my answer as correct ;-)  thanks