# Twitter Bootstrap: bottom align text next to image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

My page has a logo on the top of the page. It is around 250px high. Next to this I'd like to have three text fields bottom-aligned (with the image). The fields represent abbreviatons to english, french and german for translation purposes.

I'm using the complete bootstrap.css and added two lines (as sugested in post: [align text/image/links within a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455927/how-can-i-align-text-image-links-within-a-grid-div-of-the-twitter-bootstrap-cs)  but still can not get it working.

```
.fixedheight { height: 250px; position:relative; }
.bottomaligned {position:absolute; bottom:0; }
```

one extra css line for ENG and FRA

```
.bottomaligned2 {position:static; bottom:0; }
```

The HTML code is:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row fixedheight">
        <div class="span3 offset4">
            <img src="./images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo">
        </div><!-- /span -->
        <div class="span1 bottomaligned">
            NED
        </div><!-- /span -->
        <div class="span1 bottomaligned2">
            ENG
        </div><!-- /span -->
        <div class="span1 bottomaligned2">
            FRA
        </div><!-- /span -->
    </div><!-- /row -->
</div><!-- /container -->
</body>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to get this done?
Thanks,
Gert

Comment: When you say 'can not get it working', what _is_ it doing?

Comment: With the code as presented it shows in the left corner NED and in the middle (a bit higher) the image. Up in the right are ENG and FRA next to each other..

Comment: Just noticed `position: static` above. From http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/ "The default positioning for all elements is position:static, which means the element is not positioned and occurs where it normally would in the document. Normally you wouldn't specify this unless you needed to override a positioning that had been previously set." Should you not be using `position: absolute`?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Maybe I didn't set up my post clear. There is three lines. The 3rd line has `position: static` to have "divs" ENG and FRA not overlapping the NED div.

Comment: But surely, they are in separate divs anyway, which are controlled by the Bootstrap CSS and won't overlap whatever you put inside them.

Comment: Indeed with separate divs this should not be necessary. I'll set the whole thing up once more and report back later if a 'start from scratch' did any good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [vertical align with twitter bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592306/vertical-align-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution after some experimenting and a hint of @DaveP.

The new CSS-code:

```
.fixedheight { height: 250px; position:relative; }
.bottomaligned {position:relative; top:80%; height:10em; margin-top:-5em}
```

No need to choose `position:absolute` as the divs in Twitter Bootstrap take care of that.

The HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row fixedheight">
        <div class="span3 offset4">
            <img src="./images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo">
        </div><!-- /span -->
        <div class="bottomaligned">
        <div class="span1">
            ENG                          
        </div><!-- /span -->
        <div class="span1">
            NED
        </div><!-- /span -->
        <div class="span1">
            FRA
        </div><!-- /span -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- /row -->
</div><!-- /container -->
</body>
```

This for now gives me an image starting in the 5th column with text almost bottom-aligned on the right side of the image.