# Centering a button vertically in table cell, using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, and attempting to center a button within a table cell. I only really need it centered vertically.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-check icon-white"></i></a></td>
      <td><a href="#">Todo Item One</a><br /><span class="label label-success">One thing</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please see my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timotheus/utvUU/) for the problem. I've tried several table centering tricks I know about, but none seem to work properly. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Yes, I've tried `vertical-align:middle;`, and that works if it's inline, but not if it's in a class the `td` has. Updated the JSFiddle to reflect this.

**Final Update:** I'm an idiot, and didn't check to see if it was being overwritten by bootstrap.css

Answer (score 162, accepted):

#### FOR BOOTSTRAP 3.X:

Bootstrap now has the following style for table cells:

```
.table tbody > tr > td{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The way to go is to add your own class, adding more specificity to the previous selector:

```
.table tbody > tr > td.vert-aligned {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And then add the class to your `td`s:

```
<tr>
    <td class="vert-aligned"></td>
    ...
</tr>
```

#### FOR BOOTSTRAP 2.X

There is [no way to do this](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2750) with Bootstrap.

When used in table cells, **vertical-align** does what most people expect it to, which is to mimic the (old, deprecated) valign attribute. In a modern, standards-compliant browser, the following three code snippets do the same thing:

```
<td valign="middle"> <!-- but you shouldn't ever use valign --> </td>
<td style="vertical-align:middle"> ... </td>
<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle"> ... </div>
```

Check your [fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/utvUU/1/)

#### Further

- [vertical-align: middle with Bootstrap 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592306/vertical-align-with-twitter-bootstrap)
- [Understanding vertical-align](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)
- [Vertical alignment of elements in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

Also, you can't refer to the `td` class using `.vert` because Bootstrap already has this class:

```
.table td {
   padding: 8px;
   line-height: 20px;
   text-align: left;
   vertical-align: top; // The problem!
   border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

And is overloading the `vertical-align: middle` in '.vert' class, so you have to define this class as `td.vert`.

Comment: Thanks for linking to an updated jsfiddle. I wasn't aware when making a class statement in css, and it is table specific, you have to prepend the table element before the class name. In your example, 'td.vcenter' works, but if you change it to just '.vcenter' it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks =) Grt help without using inline css to fix it!

Comment: "vert-align" was never documented and does not appear in current Bootstrap master. When answering such questions, please stick to documented behavior.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: I'm not sure what do you mean, but I'm not saying that `vert-align` is part of Bootstrap, I'm talking about adding a **NEW** class in the main css file

Comment: Sorry, I really should have read your answer more careful before making such a strong statement.

Answer (score 43):

A little update for Bootstrap 3.

Bootstrap now has the following style for table cells:

```
.table tbody>tr>td
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The way to go is to add a your own class, with the same selector:

```
.table tbody>tr>td.vert-align
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And then add it to your tds

```
<td class="vert-align"></td>
```

Comment: Is the change officially documented?

Answer (score 15):

add this to your css

```
.table-vcenter td {
   vertical-align: middle!important;
}
```

then add to the class to your table:

```
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-vcenter">
```

Comment: I like this one because you only need to add the class in 1 place, instead of adding it in every `td`.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, i put this class on the webpage

```
<style>                        
    td.vcenter {
        vertical-align: middle !important;
        text-align: center !important;
    }
</style>
```

and this in my TemplateField

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="vcenter">
```

as the CSS class points directly to the td (tabledata) element and has the !important statment at the end each setting. It will over rule bootsraps CSS class settings.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to the `td` element that contains the button

```
<td style="vertical-align:middle;">  <--add this to center vertically
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="icon-check icon-white"></i>
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Here is the strange thing. If I do it inline, it works. If I create a class, and have the vertical-align in that, it doesn't work. I updated the jsfiddle to reflect this.

Comment: Looking at it in the debugger, I see the class 'vert' is being overridden by bootstraps css.  Inline style take precedence over css, so that's why it works.

Comment: @TimHabersack: I have added a class and is working, just use `td.vert` instead `.vert`;)

Answer (score 0):

So why is td default set to vertical-align: top;? I really don't know that yet. I would not dare to touch it. Instead add this to your stylesheet. It alters the buttons in the tables.

```
table .btn{
  vertical-align: top;
}
```