# CSS text positioning in table row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have little problem positioning text in the middle of table row.

[image]

Each table row contains three `<td>` elements. I want to position text in the middle of the  cell. Now 'Name' text where 'Description' is longer is in top.
I tired

```
td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but that doesn't work.
How to correctly position text?

**UPDATE**
This worked fine:

```
.table tbody>tr>td.vert-align{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771101/centering-a-button-vertically-in-table-cell-using-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: This is the correct css property to touch. Try to use browser debugger to see if the css is applied (it may be override by other properties).

Comment: td{text-align:center;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another great option that I find the most compliant is using the line-height property to vertically align/center ***single line*** text

```
td {
  line-height: 100px; /*play around with this value*/
}
```