# Twitter Bootstrap v2.3.2 alignment blocks height (vertical align middle and height 100%)

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm trying to align the text blocks on the height of the surrounding images.
(something like this http://s14.postimg.org/gqxt3rmu9/image.jpg)

This method [vertical-align: middle with Bootstrap 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592306/vertical-align-with-twitter-bootstrap) did not work. 
I would be grateful for any help.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            <img src="img/gallery/1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            Text
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <img src="img/gallery/1.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span6">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            <img src="img/gallery/1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            Text
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <img src="img/gallery/1.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

style

```
.row-fluid > .span3, .row-fluid > .span6 {
  display: inline-block !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important; }
```

Comment: Please share your respectively css

Comment: share css for these class row-fluid and span3 and span6..

Comment: Sorry, tried different variants. http://jsfiddle.net/beCmF/

Comment: Used display: table and display: table-cell, but then lost the responsiveness of images.