# Align text vertically with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tried the solution here:
[vertical-align with Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3)
and here:
[vertical-align: middle with Bootstrap 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592306/vertical-align-with-twitter-bootstrap)
didn't work.

This is the page:
http://yonicks.com/falican/exemple.htm

**Code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row gray_back">
         <div class="col-md-6 content_area  vcenter ">

             <div class="col-md-2"></div>

             <div class="col-md-10 vcenter">
                 <h1 >text here need to be in the middle vertically</h1>
                 <h1 > also this</h1>
             </div>


             <div class="the_p_area">
                 <div class="col-md-2"> </div>

                  <div class="col-md-10">
                      also this also this also this also this also this also this also this also this

                  </div>

             </div>

         </div>


         <div class="col-md-6">
             <img src="img/fff.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
                        <br>
         </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap.

How can I make the text align vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were close.

```
.row > .col-md-6 {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use! line-height. The property vertical-align is very specific

for exapmple:

```
.yourclas{
 line-height: 2;
}
```